# getting average of group of numbers from a .txt file in python

Tags: python, list

I am trying to get the average of a group of numbers in a .txt file. It worked when numbers are like this: every number on a separate line

```
363
186
262
247
:
```

but my .txt file is like this:

```
237, 321, 212, 379, 201, 247, 201, 204, 298, 130
285, 229, 167, 235, 353, 176, 130, 274, 337, 192
......
```

note: 1000 numbers.
How to fix this?

This is what I tried:

```
import os

def averg_int(path):
   lst = []
   with open(path, "r") as file:
     for line in file: # Read one line at the time
        n = int(line.strip()) # Strip and convert to integer
        lst.append(n)
        avg=sum(lst)/len(last)
   return avg
```

Comment: `line.split(', ')` produces the numbers as a list, provided the line is consistently formatted. But having a braindead input format is probably something you want to fix separately, so that you can use standard tools to manipulate the file (count number of records, find duplicates, etc etc).

Comment: @tripleee this worked but it read only the last line how to fix it

Comment: Obviously, loop over the lines and do this for each line.

Comment: @tripleee sorry I am taking from your time can you please tell me how I beginner and I am trying to fix this from yesterday

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`split` each line and `extend` the list with those values.

The `import` was unnecessary so I took it out.

```py
def averg_int(path):
   lst = []
   with open(path, "r") as file:
     for line in file: # Read one line at the time
        numbers = [int(x) for x in line.rstrip('\n').split(', ')]
        lst.extend(numbers)
   return sum(lst)/len(lst)
```

Notice that `line` will contain a newline at the end, so we remove that, too. Also, you hal misspelled the variable once (`last` pro `lst`).

Comment: thank you a lot man I appreciate your help

Answer (score 0):

The problem is with `n = int(line.strip())` part, because you have multiple numbers in a single line, you need to `split` them and then type cast to `int`:

```py
n = [int(i.strip()) for i in line.split()]
```

Comment: this works but read only the first line how to fix it ??